# Consistent indexing and categorizing of categorical fields

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

Suppose I have the following Scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (0, "a"),
  (1, "b"),
  (2, "c"),
  (3, "a"),
  (4, "a"),
  (5, "c")
)).toDF("id", "category")

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("category")
  .setOutputCol("categoryIndex")
  .fit(df)
val indexed = indexer.transform(df)
```

Now, suppose I create an `org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.DecisionTreeModel` that uses this indexer and save the model to a file.

How can I ensure that if I do predictions on new data in the future that the indexer will be consistent with the original indexer used on the original data to construct the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persist and re-load the indexer too

Comment: I thought of that.  Not the most elegant solution.  However, if that's the only way.

Comment: Yeah, it gets slightly annoying. However, if you want a positive in there, you can take the opportunity to re partition / coalesce your data / model as you persist it, making execution faster in the future. Spark has a habit of over-paralleling some stuff, based on the assumption you have massive data. Usually you can manage it better yourself and get crazy performance improvements.